# Compiling issues on STTwitter for OSX App

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, sttwitter

I've been working on an app for OSX (not my own, one that I am to maintain) that needs Twitter integrations and found the STTwitter wrapper. It says it's compatible down to OSX 10.7. However, when I try to compile it, I run into several compilation issues that I've tracked I think I've tracked down to not being able to compile with Objective-C literal subscripts.

I tries using the workaround suggested across the web for adding my own interfaces, but that didn't seem to help.

The first compilation error I get is "Array subscript is not an integer" at the following chunk of code in NSError+STTwitter.m:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    md[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = message;
    if(underlyingError) md[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = underlyingError;
    if(rateLimitLimit) md[kSTTwitterRateLimitLimit] = rateLimitLimit;
    if(rateLimitRemaining) md[kSTTwitterRateLimitRemaining] = rateLimitRemaining;
    if(rateLimitResetDate) md[kSTTwitterRateLimitResetDate] = rateLimitResetDate;
```

If I comment that code out, just to see what happens (the literal substring I believe), I get more issues in STTwitterOS.m

```
NSString *value = [keyValue[1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

[md setObject:value forKey:keyValue[0]];
```

Those give "Bad receiver type NSArray" and "Sending NSArray to parameter of incompatible type 'id

Any help would be appreciated. My objective c coding isn't that great....

Comment: More information - The tools used in the project are built for 32-bit architecture. Perhaps this is why? I'm fairly new to Obj-C and XCode.

Comment: Make sure you're compiling with Xcode 5.

Comment: I think that for some reason your compiler does not accept Objective-C litterals http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/ is it a compiling options issues? can you just compile the demo project that comes with STTwitter?